# D3 - Disable/Reenable mouseover on certain layers

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm completely new to both D3 and JavaScript, so I'm not even sure of the best way to go about searching for an answer to my problem. I am currently trying to adapt this [Interactive Scatter Plot/Legend](https://bl.ocks.org/floofydugong/9c94ab01d8c3ed8ea3821d4a7e119b07) to my own data. I've gotten it working, but one issue I noticed – which turned out to be an issue in the original as well, though I hadn't noticed it at first – is that when layers are hidden, the mouseover tip still fires for invisible buttons.

Is there a way to adapt the code so that hidden layers aren't just invisible, but no longer trigger a mouseover event either, such that lower layers previously covered by an upper layer will be accessible by mouseover, once the upper layer has been hidden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing the less possible amount of changes in that code, just set `pointer-events` to `none` before the filter and to `all` after the filter:

```
legend.on("click", function(type) {
    d3.selectAll(".dot")
        .style("opacity", 0.0)
        .attr("pointer-events", "none")
        .filter(function(d) {
            return d["first_careunit"] == type;
        })
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .attr("pointer-events", "all")
        .style("stroke", "black")
});
```

Of course, with a big refactor, there are best ways to do that.

Here is the updated bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/a2d323f9ef49e864ee589158b50cbaec/1d33bf045be6aeab83bb7c348354f1f10481f7b6

Not related to your question, but from a user's perspective it's annoying the fact that you can select a category but you cannot unselect it (that is, view all) after that.

Comment: Yeah, not being able to re-view all bothered me as well. Was planning on figuring that out next :)